# Want to leave a domain/set account as administrator

Tags: domain-controller

I have a laptop used for school but since I've graduated long ago I wanted to remove my laptop from the school's domain, so I changed the settings and now I'm under a workgroup which sucks because after restarting the computer, my documents are gone so I suppose I'm not using the same account anymore and I have even *less* control of my laptop than I did before.

I wish to get complete control of my computer, do I need to factory reset it?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the local account you are now using has admin privileges then you have as much control over the computer as before - probably more as the domain might have been enforcing policies

If you want to access your previous documents, go to c:\users and then go into the folder that would have been used by your domain account - it should be the same as your domain username.

No need to reinstall at all.

Further to you comments, as you no longer have admin rights, you will either need to reinstall, or use something like [this](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-7-password-recovery.html) in order to reset your administrator password.

Comment: Unfortunately my account doesn't have admin privileges now (I can't go into anything that has the tiny admin logo beside it) and at the logon page there isn't any other account other than the one that I'm on now that I can log into so I'm at my wit's end...

Comment: You could try something like [this](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-7-password-recovery.html) to reset your administrator password. Otherwise, it will be a case of reinstalling, I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried to run the program but it needs an admin account to do so so I think I'll be resetting it. Thank you for helping!

Comment: I haven't used that specific program before, but normally you would create a boot disk on any computer, and then boot from that on your computer to reset the password. Take a look at this [video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dfSNMdqJVv8) which shows a similar process using [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) which you can get for free.

Answer (score 0):

Once you remove your computer from domain, your user folder becomes something else. In order to have your files back, you need to copy them from your old folder to your new folder and grab the ownership of them. And that's it.